# my mac is asking me if I want to allow it to access information on an *unknown* iPhone ... why?

Tags: mac, security, itunes, iphone

When I came into my office this morning, my Mac Pro had an iTunes popup (#1):

> Do you want to allow this computer to access information on "John
>    Doe's iPhone"?
>
> If you don't allow access, you will not be able to manage or sync
>    your iPhone with this computer     [cancel]   [continue]

"John Doe" is our new janitor ...  note that he does not know any of our WiFi passwords,  and is unlikely to be on our internal or our semi-public Wi-Fi network.

So, did he cable his phone to my Mac, triggering this question?

If not, what's configured in *his* iPhone that's different from other office visitors, since I've not seen this before?

Obviously, if he connected his iPhone to my Mac, I've got a major concern!!
 
(Using iTunes 12.4.1.6, OS X 10.11.5)

thanks,
 Stan

1. I saw the popup after I woke the Mac up from 'sleep', which requires a password.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. As for "why?" Corporate Spy moonlighting for the CIA who forgot his iphone charger?

Comment: While I suspect Michael is correct, I was hoping that it was more innocent, and that there was some iPhone feature I wasn't aware of to faciliate wireless connections :)     The conjecture now is that the janitor needed to charge his phone and didn't realize the consequences.